# trigonometric integral with tangent

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\biggl( \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sin x+1}{\cos x}}+\sqrt[3]\frac{\sin x-1}{\cos x}\biggr)\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\,dx ,\;x\in\Bigl(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)$$ Can somebody give some tips about how can I evaluate this integral,please? I observed that $\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$ is the derivative of tangent, but I don't know how to do it using the substitution $t=\tan x$ because there will be $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ inside and I think there is another method.

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate the integral with the limits $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$, or the indefinite integral?

Comment: Maybe it should be $\frac{1+\sin{x}}{\cos^2x}$ instead $\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$?

Comment: Notice, that, when you substitute $x + \pi$ for $x$ in the integrand, you get the same function, so according to wikipedia, a sensible change of variable will be $\tan$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use integration by parts twice. First we write
\begin{align}
I &= \int \left (\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sin x + 1}{\cos x}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sin x - 1}{\cos x}} \right ) \sec^2 x \, dx\\
&= \int \big{(}\sqrt[3]{\tan x + \sec x} + \sqrt[3]{\tan x - \sec x} \big{)} \sec^2 x \, dx.
\end{align}

If we let
$$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{\tan x + \sec x} + \sqrt[3]{\tan x - \sec x}$$
and
$$g(x) = \sqrt[3]{\tan x + \sec x} - \sqrt[3]{\tan x - \sec x},$$
then obsereve that
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{3} \sec x \cdot g(x) \quad \text{and} \quad g'(x) = \frac{1}{3} \sec x \cdot f(x).$$
So for the integral we have
\begin{align}
I &= \int \sec^2 x \cdot f(x) \, dx\\
&= f(x) \cdot \tan x - \int \tan x \cdot f'(x) \, dx \qquad \text{(by parts)}\\
&= f(x) \cdot \tan x - \frac{1}{3} \int \sec x \tan x \cdot g(x) \, dx \\
&= f(x) \cdot \tan x - \frac{1}{3} \sec x \cdot g(x) + \frac{1}{3} \int \sec x \cdot g'(x) \, dx \quad \text{(by parts)}\\
&= f(x) \cdot \tan x - \frac{1}{3} \sec x \cdot g(x) + \frac{1}{9} \int \sec^2 x \cdot f(x) \, dx\\
&= f(x) \cdot \tan x - \frac{1}{3} \sec x \cdot g(x) + \frac{1}{9} I,
\end{align}
giving
$$I = \frac{9}{8} \tan x \cdot f(x) - \frac{3}{8} \sec x \cdot g(x) + C$$
or 
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{9}{8} \tan x \big{(} \sqrt[3]{\tan x + \sec x} + \sqrt[3]{\tan x - \sec x} \big{)}\\
& \qquad - \frac{3}{8} \sec x \big{(} \sqrt[3]{\tan x + \sec x} - \sqrt[3]{\tan x - \sec x} \big{)} + C.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

First note that if $f$ is a function with antiderivative $F$, then the antiderivative of its inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ is $F( f^{-1}(x))-xf^{-1}(x)$, which can be easily shown by differentiating.

Now let's consider your integral.

Making a trigonometric substitution allows us to consider instead the following integrand:
$$s(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Notice that $s$ satisfies the property
$$s=\sqrt[3]{2x-3s}$$
or
$$s^3+3s=2x$$
If $t$ is the inverse function of $s$ so that $s(t(x))=x$ and $t(s(x))=x$, we have from the above equation that
$$2t=x^3+3x$$
Thus, we may use the formula mentioned at the beginning of the post to solve your integral. The antiderivative of $t$ with respect to $x$ is
$$T(x)=\frac{x^4+6x^2}{8}$$
and so the antiderivative of $s$ is given by
$$S(x)=T(s(x))-xs(x)$$
where $T$ and $s$ are defined above. This yields the desired result, and now all you have to do is undo the trig substitution at the beginning, and the value of your integral is
$$T(s(\tan(x)))-\tan(x)s(\tan(x))$$

Comment: Is the approach taken here a known method to approach a certain family(ies) of integrals? (similar to say the Half Tangent substitution method for rational trigonometric functions)

Comment: @DavidG Not that I know of. I just worked it out from scratch.

Comment: How did you get that expresion of s(x) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: NONONONONO it makes things wayyyyy worse

Comment: This gives $$\int\left(\sqrt[3]\frac{1+t}{1-t}+\sqrt[3]\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right)\frac{2(1+t^2)}{(1-t^2)^2}\,dt$$...what then?

Comment: Now i would substitute the roots.